# Angular 5 connect postgreSQL

Tags: angular, postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to connect to the postgreSQL database.

I use the tutorial:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started

I do not know where to put the code to connect to the database?

```
import {Sequelize} from '@angular/sequelize';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/neme_database');

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
 console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});


const UserLogin = sequelize.define('user', {
  userName: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
});


UserLogin.findAll().then(users => {
   console.log(users)
});
```

Comment: I would like to use the UserLogin.findAll() method in login/login.component.ts .  I installed only:
npm install sequelize

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to split your code into at least three files:

config.js

```
import {Sequelize} from '@angular/sequelize';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/neme_database');

export sequlize
```

in you index.js you import your config and connect to database

```
import { sequlize } from 'path-to-config/config.js`

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
 console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

user models models/user.js

```
export const UserLogin = sequelize.define('user', {
  userName: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
});
```

Then in your controller inside function such as

```
getAllUser() {
  return UserLogin.findAll()
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I added the question wrong. Is above Jerry Chen's response

Answer (score 0):

Code now has the following structure:

```
- app
 -- auth
  --- auth.quard.ts
  --- auth.service.ts
  --- user.ts
 - home
  --- home.component.html
  --- home.component.ts
 - login  
  --- login.component.html
  --- login.component.ts
 - models
  --- UserLogin.js
 - app.routing.models.ts
 - app.components.ts
 - app.components.html
 - app.models.ts
 - config.js
 - index.js
```

Should I install to connect to the database?

```
        npm install express --save       
        npm install passport --save          
        npm install passport-local --save            
        npm install body-parser --save           
        npm install express-session --save           
        npm install bcrypt-nodejs --save             
        npm install express-handlebars --save
```

I put the getAllUser method in auth / auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { User } from './user';
import {UserLogin}  from './models/userLogin.js';


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);   

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  login(user: User) {
    if (user.userName !== '' && user.password !== '' )  {
      this.loggedIn.next(true);       
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

  getAllUser() {
   return UserLogin.findAll();
  }
}
```

but it returns an error message:

```
 Failed to compile.

./src/app/auth/auth.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './models/userLogin.js' in 
'C:\myPath\name_project\src\app\auth'
@ ./src/app/auth/auth.service.ts 15:21-53
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

app/models/userLogin.js:

```
    const UserLogin = sequelize.define('user', {
        userName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
    });


    UserLogin.findAll().then(users => {
          console.log(users)
        });
```